# How to parse FirebaseAuthException exception message (Admin SDK Java)?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Admin SDK Java API v6.12.2.

I call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().generatePasswordResetLink(email, actionCodeSettings)` to generate a password reset link for users. If the email isn't registered, I get a big blob of text with embedded JSON from `e.getMessage()`.

The looked at the `FirebaseAuthException` doc and it only exposes one method `e.getErrorCode()`, which in this case returns `internal-error`.

I can certainly parse this text to look for "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND" and translate it into a user-friendly message. But isn't that a very clumsy error message? At least, there should have been methods to return the error code 400, and a simple String message, and the details could go into a JSON object.

What is the recommended approach here by the Firebase team and how are other developers handling it?

Output of `e.getMessage()`:

```
Unexpected HTTP response with status: 400; body: {
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: With the current state of the SDK you cannot do any better than trying to parse the above error message yourself. But after https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/354 is resolved you will have some more control over this.

Comment: Okay, thank you. @HiranyaJayathilaka